# Making my catalog public on THREDDS

Tags: tomcat, server, catalog-service, thredds

I have been assigned a task to create a THREDDS server so our lab can start uploading data online. I managed to learn how to download and work with Tomcat/THREDDS and established our own local server. I have also been feeding data into the server without any problems so far, but I am confused on how can I make my catalog available for the public.

The local server can only be accessed from our computer or through remote access as far as I understand; but how does one make it available for open access so users can access and download data? I know databases such as Hycom have a THREDDS catalog page in their domain.

How can I make this possible?

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me as a problem network configuration.

But, in this link you have the basic tutorial:
https://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/tds/current/tutorial/GettingStarted.html

and in this other link the advanced tutorial for production configuration:
https://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/tds/current/tutorial/Security.html

where there is 2 section related to IP and firewall configuration